# SourceForge to GitHub: "remote origin already exists."

Tags: git

I am trying to move my SourceForge svn repo ("Loyc") to GitHub. I tried both the "git svn" approach...

```
> git svn init --prefix=svn/ --no-metadata --trunk=https://svn.code.sf.net/p/loyc/code/
> git svn fetch
...
> git branch --all
* master
  remotes/svn/trunk
```

And (after deleting and recreating the folder) the svn2git approach...

```
> svn2git https://svn.code.sf.net/p/loyc/code/ --rootistrunk -v --authors ../authors.txt
...
> git branch --all
* master
  remotes/svn/trunk
> dir /ad /b
.git
Lib
Src
VeryOldDocs
Visual Studio Integration
```

(Apparently SourceForge does not use the "standard" svn layout, or at least my repo doesn't.)

In either case there is a mysterious "origin" defined:

```
> git remote --verbose
origin
upstream
```

GitHub [advises these commands](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-subversion):

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:GITHUB_USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git
git push origin master
```

although it advised these commands instead when I added a new repo at GitHub (what's the difference?):

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/qwertie/Loyc.git
git push -u origin master
```

But...

```
> git remote add origin https://github.com/qwertie/Loyc.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

and I can't get rid of 'origin':

```
> git remote rename origin mystery-origin
error: Could not rename config section 'remote.origin' to 'remote.mystery-origin'
> git remote remove origin
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.origin'
```

and I can't look at it either...

```
> git remote show origin
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What's going on? This is not normal right? What do I do?

```
> git version
git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1
> ver
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
```

Comment: Is the config file really writable?

Comment: Which config file? `.git\config` is not read-only.

Comment: Yes, `.git\config`. But is it *writable*? Is no other process accessing it?

Comment: @poke Yes, I can load and save it in a text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe you must have a `[remote "origin"]` section in either your global **`~/.gitconfig`** or **`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`**, or alternatively the system-wide **`/etc/gitconfig`** on your box.

Manually delete the section, then verify that origin doesn’t show up anymore in the `git remote show` output and you shall be right.

If you cannot edit the files you will have to setup your shell or alias your git command to run with `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM` and `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` set such that git will ignore the pre-sets.

Comment: Ahh, I found it: `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\GitHub\PortableGit_ca477551eeb4aea0e4ae9fcd3358bd96720bb5c8\etc\gitconfig`. The `[remote "origin"]` section contains two lines, `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` and `fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`. I have no idea what that means, but assuming these lines were added by the GitHub app, it's a bit odd that GitHub help says nothing about the issue. Here's hoping the git people work on their error messages at some point. Removing the section does allow the `add origin` command to work.